# dynamic absolute path symlinks

Tags: linux, symlink

Is there a way to create dynamic absolute paths for symlinks?

Every time I tried creating a symlink with a relative path, the link was resolving as broken. The only option I had was to create the symlink with an absolute path

```
    ex. ln -s $PATH/folder docroot/folder1
```

While this worked, when I pushed the code to the remote server, the path was still looking within my home directory and causing a permissions denied error. 
So, I was wondering if there was a way to fake the absolute path?

File structure of project looks like this:

```
SiteName
  Docroot
     folder
     folder
     folder
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. A symbolic link points exactly to the path you specify. It is irrelevant if that is a relative or an absolute path. The example you posted does _not_ use an absolute path, so I wonder if you really are using the terms `absolute` and `relative` in the correct way...

Comment: Sorry, changed $PTH to $PATH. This is global variable that returns the absolute path you are in. So the target was in essence: User/MyName/Sites/projects/SiteName/docroot/folder and the link was docroot/folder1

Comment: I tried creating a symlink from the docroot and project root but every time the link was broken. So when I tried to cd into the folder1 i got a' not a file or directory' error.

Comment: You said "$PATH. This is global variable that returns the absolute path you are in."   No, it isn't.  Try $PWD.

Comment: @hymie is right. And on top: `User/MyName/Sites/projects/SiteName/docroot/folder` is _not_ an absolute path. `/User/MyName/Sites/projects/SiteName/docroot/folder` _would_ be an absolute path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original idea to use relative linking was perfectly appropriate, but most likely just wasn't implemented correctly. To correctly create relative symlinks:

- Given directory structure:

  ```
  SiteName
    docroot
       folder
  ```
- Your current working dir: `SiteName`
- You want: `docroot/folder1 -> docroot/folder`

Try:

```
$ ln -s folder docroot/folder1
```

If you had the `tree` program, you could see the structure, as well as the symlink `folder1` successfully pointing to `docroot`'s `folder`:

```
$ tree
.
└── docroot
    ├── folder
    └── folder1 -> folder

3 directories, 0 files
```

### Explanation

Your original attempt at relative links failed likely due to a common misunderstanding about what is required for the `relative` link:

[Shadur's Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10373/135509) mentions:

> Symbolic links are relative to the location the link is in, not the location you were when you created the link. ...

So,

- From `folder1`'s perspective, relative path to `folder` is simply `folder` since they are siblings of the same directory
- The command syntax is `ln -s <relative path> <where to create new link>`
- When running the command from `SiteName`, the new link would be created at `docroot/folder1`

So the final command is `ln -s folder docroot/folder1` to correctly create at `docroot/folder1` to point to `folder` within the same directory.

So it will now work as long as you don't change their relative locations.